# Is posible to use Vanilla HTML in a React web app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm currently working in a React web app and to save time, a work collegue helped me with the landing page. He did it using vanilla HTML, CSS and vanilla JS.

My question is, can I use that landing without having to adapt it to react? I know I could wrap all the code in a div and go on. But the JS librarys that he used, have to ve adapted.

I tried doing a npm build, create a index.html and place the build folder under it in a folder called "trade". I was trying to create a structure like: "http://ip-server/" is the index.html that I created. And "http://ip-server/trade/" is the react app. I used Docker with Nginx for it. But it didn't seem to work. All I could reach was the index.html, never the build folder.

Am I missing something? Or is it better to adapt the landing?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the "div" technique to adapt the landing page. For that you'd could use "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" as pointed out here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

And then you'll need to research how to make the third party javascript from that landing page work in React in case per case basis. This will be useful for you also for future cases if you can afford to invest the time now. I hope this helps!